# Generic typed dictionary in Elm

Tags: f#, elm

I am curious how to port this from F# to Elm:

```
type World =
    { Rooms: Map<RoomId, Room> 
      Player: Player }
```

The thing between RoomId, Room is called a generic type dictionary. 
See here the context: https://github.com/ShalokShalom/Elchemist/blob/master/Game.fs

I read something about type variables, can they help?
If so, how?

Thanks :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Elm's syntax would be similar.

*Edit* - @dogbert is right about RoomId not being comparable in my original answer. You could use a type alias of a String instead.

```
type alias RoomId = String

type alias Room =
    { id: RoomId
    , details: Details
    , items: List Item
    , exits: Exits 
    }

type alias World =
    { rooms: Dict RoomId Room
    , player: Player
    }
```

Comment: You can't do anything with the Dict in this case though because `RoomId` is not `comparable`.

Comment: So how would you do it?

Comment: Wonderful, thanks a lot. 
(Chad reworked his answer based on your feedback)
Solved ^-^